# TypeError: 'hmac_hash_module' is an invalid keyword argument for pbkdf2_hmac()

Tags: python-3.x, hmac, sha512, pbkdf2

I am trying to compute a master key with the pbkdf2_hmac. Please help me with the latest arguments that we need to pass in the pbkdf2_hmac for computing the key.

```
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac, sha512

def computeMasterKey(mp, ds):
    password = mp.encode()
    salt = ds.encode()
    key = pbkdf2_hmac(password, salt, 32, iterations=1000000, hmac_hash_module=sha512)
    return key
```

Error: TypeError: 'hmac_hash_module' is an invalid keyword argument for pbkdf2_hmac()

I tried the follwoing

1.

`key = pbkdf2_hmac(password, salt, 32, iterations=1000000, hash_name=sha512)`

Error: TypeError: argument for pbkdf2_hmac() given by name ('hash_name') and position (1)

2.

`key = pbkdf2_hmac(password, salt, 32, iterations=1000000, algorithm=sha512)`

Error: TypeError: 'algorithm' is an invalid keyword argument for pbkdf2_hmac()

3.

```py
key = pbkdf2_hmac(password, salt, 32, iterations=1000000, hash_name='sha512')
```

Error: TypeError: argument for pbkdf2_hmac() given by name ('hash_name') and position (1)

Expectation: Please help me with the latest arguments that we need to pass in the pbkdf2_hmac for computing the key.

Comment: I think you can simply solve this by giving the `hash_name` as string instead of imported class. My name is Maarten, I'm not my name... Try `"sha512"` for instance including the quotation marks.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes tried </br>     key = pbkdf2_hmac(password, salt, 32, iterations=1000000, hash_name='sha512')

Comment: Oh, the signature is `hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(hash_name, password, salt, iterations, dklen=None)`.... So the parameters seem to be in the wrong order. The password should be provided as `password.encode()` as it should be bytes.... That later issue probably mucked up the order of the arguments.

Comment: Solved with ```key = pbkdf2_hmac(hash_name='sha512', password=password, salt=salt, iterations=1000000, dklen=32)```

Comment: Alright. You might still want to explicitly encode the password as the encoding of the string *before* the hashing / key derivation is not officially part of PBKDF2. But problem solved :)